# Python: return list from for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, return

so I have

```
packs_purchased = (10, 6, 36)
dice_purchased = (2, 0, 1)
board_games_purchased = (3, 2, 0)
```

and

```
prices = (4.25, 125, 11, 50)
```

How do I get this for loop to return a list and not just the output

```
for packs_purchased in packs_purchased:
    if packs_purchased < 35:
        packs_spent = packs_purchased * prices[0]
    else:
        packs_spent = (int(math.floor(packs_purchased / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((packs_purchased % 36) * prices[0])
    print("%.2f" % packs_spent)
```

right now it prints

```
42.50
25.50
125.00
```

and I want it to return a list, something like

```
packs_spent(42.50, 25.50, 125.00)
```

Comment: Append `packs_spent` to a list, and return that at the end.

Comment: BTW, don't use the same variable for the list and iteration variable `for packs_purchased in packs_purchased:`. Use something like `for pack in packs_purchased:` instead.

Comment: Also, `packs_spent(42.50, 25.50, 125.00)` is not a list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a list prior to the `for` loop, and then append to that list instead of printing.

```
packs_spent = []
for pack in packs_purchased:
    if pack < 35:
        spent = pack * prices[0]
    else:
        spent = (int(math.floor(pack / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((pack % 36) * prices[0])
    packs_spent.append(spent)

print(packs_spent)
# [42.5, 25.5, 125.0]
```

To print with the proper number of decimal places, and in the format shown in the question, you can use a list comprehension:

```
print("packs_spent(", 
      ', '.join(f"{i:.2f}" for i in packs_spent),
      ")",
      sep="")
# packs_spent(42.50, 25.50, 125.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an empty list and append results into that list.

```
packs_list = []    
for packs_purchased in packs_purchased:
   if packs_purchased < 35:
        packs_spent = packs_purchased * prices[0]
   else:
        packs_spent = (int(math.floor(packs_purchased / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((packs_purchased % 36) * prices[0])
packs_list.append(packs_spent)
print(packs_list)
```

Comment: An explanation for the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few silly mistakes in your Python code as well as some styling error (but we are not going there, as it's not that important).

The mistake includes, you are using same `variable` for iteration variable as well as for `iterable`, it can create major confusion when using the `iterable` for future use, and you might get `int` instead of `tuple`.

Also, *side note*, `list comprehension` has variable in `local` scope instead of `global`, so it will not create confusion, but still I recommend changing the iteration varable name.

@Green Cloak Guy have already stated the answer, but it can be improvised using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). It also helps in usage of slightly less memory than that of `list`, less usage of lines and also less time consumption. I would suggest using `array` by [numpy](https://numpy.org/), but let's leave it.

```py
print([f'{packs * prices[0]:.2f}' if packs < 35 else f'{(int(math.floor(packs / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((packs % 36) * prices[0]):.2f}' for packs in packs_purchased])
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> [42.50, 25.50, 125.00]
```

The output above is called `list` and not what you have stated in your desired output.
If you want that output, you can do, just what @Green Cloak Guy did, but still here's an example:

```py
CREATED_LIST = [f'{packs * prices[0]:.2f}' if packs < 35 else f'{(int(math.floor(packs / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((packs % 36) * prices[0]):.2f}' for packs in packs_purchased]
print(f'packs_spent({", ".join(CREATED_LIST)})')
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> packs_spent(42.50, 25.50, 125.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
packs_purchased = (10, 6, 36)
dice_purchased = (2, 0, 1)
board_games_purchased = (3, 2, 0)
prices = (4.25, 125, 11, 50)

result = []
for packs_purchased in packs_purchased:
    if packs_purchased < 35:
        packs_spent = packs_purchased * prices[0]
    else:
        packs_spent = (int(math.floor(packs_purchased / 36)) * prices[1]) + ((packs_purchased % 36) * prices[0])
    a = ("%.2f" % packs_spent)
    result.append(a)
    
result = list(map(float, result))
print("packs_spent:", (result))
```

Comment: Already answered in the same way above